# Set navigation bar back button text IOS

Tags: iphone, uinavigationbar, back-button

Hi I am developing Iphone application in which I want to set some text for my back button. I tried in following way :

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.topItem.title = @"NOTIFICATION";
```

It is working fine if I gave small text but if I gave long text then it is not showing my text. Instead of that it is showing default "Back" text. How to do this? Any one know about it? Need some help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**It is the default behaviour brother.**

If you want to display long text (which you should not - because if you display long back button text then there'll be no space available to display `TITLE` of current view controller.)

Although you can achieve it using your own back button (Write below code in the `viewcontroller2`).

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setTitle:@"asdas" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitleColor:[UIColor greenColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
[button addTarget:self.navigationController action:@selector(popViewControllerAnimated:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

UIBarButtonItem *customBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = customBarItem;
```

Comment: Thank you akshit. It works but it shows only title. It is not showing like back button. I mean it is without back icon.

Comment: you need to use custom image & then `setImage` to `button`. Customization comes at a price..

Comment: Ohh ok. So its like button with image and text. Is there any way so that I can use system default back image?

Comment: No, You can use photoshop & edit this image, http://erfjax.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/7a260_apple_ios_samples_xwOa0.jpg

Delete unwanted portion.